# How to connect PostgreSQL database using Gorm

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I am unable to connect to PostgreSQL.

```golang
var db *gorm.DB
var err error
func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    var err error
    db, err = gorm.Open("postgres", "host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres dbname=dvdrental password=12345")
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }
```

I am expecting database to be connected and fetching api.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry,i am using this command  db, err = gorm.Open("postgres", "host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres dbname=dvdrental password=12345")

Comment: If that's what you're using, then update your question to show that.

Comment: I am getting "failed to connect database"

Comment: Print the err, that will give you more information? Are you able to connect to the database using the same connection details from the console? Do you want to add `sslmode=disable`?

Comment: No, you're not getting "failed to connect database" -- that's the message YOU wrote. You need to show the actual error returned by the `Open` function.

Comment: Its showing   sql: database is closed

Comment: Now, i am getting "dial tcp: lookup user=: no such host" & "sql: database is closed"

Comment: How are you getting two errors?

Comment: In any case, the errors are pretty obvious. You have an invalid hostname in your connection string.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got the solution.

Answer (score 6):

This is the best way I found to connect to postgres.

```
import _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
```

```
dsn := url.URL{
        User:     url.UserPassword(conf.User, conf.Password),
        Scheme:   "postgres",
        Host:     fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", conf.Host, conf.Port),
        Path:     conf.DBName,
        RawQuery: (&url.Values{"sslmode": []string{"disable"}}).Encode(),
    }
    db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", dsn.String())
```

Comment: This is very helpful, please don't go about building your own connection string, I've wasted over an hour trying to figure out why I keep creating tables into the wrong database.
+1 for this answer, thank you so much @oskank-kumar

Comment: i get error on the "url", could someone help?

Comment: Where did you get this from? That method signature does not exist in gorm. The first parameter is *Dialector* and not string. This answer is wrong

Answer (score 4):

Followed the official docs and it worked for me,
Visit https://gorm.io/docs/connecting_to_the_database.html

```
import (
  "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
  "gorm.io/gorm"
)

dsn := "host=localhost user=gorm password=gorm dbname=gorm port=9920 sslmode=disable TimeZone=Asia/Shanghai"
db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
```

I just had to remove the host variable and enter rest of the details and it works.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30768298)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the question keeps spaces for imagination.

Anyway, here're the possible use-cases why you're not able to connect gorm to postgres:

1. Make sure your postgres is well running in the host you have specified (in this case: localhost)
2. If it's alright, make sure your user and password is alright

If everything is ok, you can check in the CLI:

```
$ sudo -i -u postgres
$ psql
```

If it's successful, that means something else in the code. As far as I can see, you did not show the import section. Did you silently import the postgres gorm dialects?

```
import _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
```